# How to fix log error when opening eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, error-log

When I open the eclipse IDE, I get an error in the log but I don't really know what to do

Log:

!ENTRY net.sf.eclipse.tomcat 4 0 2022-11-15 19:00:16.144
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: net.sf.eclipse.tomcat [46]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)`

With what was on the internet, I tried deleting the .eclipse and the files from C:\Users\MYNAME\eclipse\jee-2020-12\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager

Comment: _"With what was on the internet"_ you probably wrecked your installation. Does a fresh installation work?

Comment: `net.sf.eclipse.tomcat` is definitely not in a fresh installation of the "jee" IDE.